# Can I use the Raspberry Pi openCV version with the Java wrapper running with Java SE embedded?

Tags: java, opencv, raspberry-pi, webcam, raspbian

I will try to explain what I am trying to do, as it seems to be relevant in order to understand my question.

I am currently trying to do face recognition from a webcam connected to a Raspberry Pi and using the openCV Java wrapper.

Can I use the Raspberry Pi openCV version with the Java wrapper running with Java SE embedded?

Comment: no idea about raspi here, but to make the FaceRecognition work with opencv's java wrappers, you will need some extra bits of JNI even (missing create***Recognizer functions)

Comment: @Rotka are you planning to use a regular camera or the Pi Camera module ?